# How can i extract data from this line?

Tags: bash, sed, grep

```
xyz /mnp/opq/p/1926081/sp/192608100/serveFlavor/entryId/0_ffx7sljc/v/2/flavorId/0_,n6h1xlhl,ea3anltg,jfs8boo9,w2v1vsk2,ze8e1q2s,to8w2p18,/forceproxy/true/name/new
```

in this line this part `,n6h1xlhl,ea3anltg,jfs8boo9,w2v1vsk2,ze8e1q2s,to8w2p18,` is variable so it could be more or less number of data between the comas in the parts `xyz /mnp/opq/p/1926081/sp/192608100/serveFlavor/entryId/0_` everything is constant except the numerical value 1926081 or 192608100 can increase or decrease.`/forceproxy/true/name/new` is also a constant and does not change

The output i want is such that only the last value of the pattern `,n6h1xlhl,ea3anltg,jfs8boo9,w2v1vsk2,ze8e1q2s,to8w2p18,` `is included and rest is deleted including any comma and the initial`xyz`

so it should be :
`/mnp/opq/p/1926081/sp/192608100/serveFlavor/entryId/0_ffx7sljc/v/2/flavorId/0_to8w2p18/forceproxy/true/name/new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `munish.txt` contains the sample data you provided, then:

```
$ sed -e 's/^[^ ]* //; s/,.*,\([^,]*\),/\1/' munish.txt
/mnp/opq/p/1926081/sp/192608100/serveFlavor/entryId/0_ffx7sljc/v/2/flavorId/0_to8w2p18/forceproxy/true/name/new
```

This `sed` script deletes everything up to and including the first space in a line, and everything from the first `,` to the second-last `,`.  Also deletes the final `,`.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="[, ]"} {print $2$(NF-1)$NF}' input_filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a wierd way of doing it doesn't look good
where variable `v` contains the whole line

```
echo $(echo ${v%%,*})$(echo ${v} | grep -Po '.*,\K.*(?=,)')$(echo ${v##*,}) | sed 's/xyz\s//p'
```